# create an instance of Activity with Activity class object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have got an Activity class by:

```
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());

String activityClassName = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();

Class<?> activityClazz = Class.forName(activityClassName);
```

Is it possible to create an instance of this Activity by using the `activityClazz` ? If so, how?

(My code is in a independent java class. Not in activity or service. )

Comment: Yes  , you can. But you have to indicate the package when your class is, in the same string of activity ClassName you have to concatenate. And obviosly trow to the class not found exception. Regards

Comment: you could, but there is no good reason to do so. it would result in an uninitialized state of your activity, that you cannot use for anything.

Answer (score 6):

Technically, you can create an instance of an `Activity` like this. However, this instance would be useless because its underlying `Context` would not have been set up.

The rule is that you should never ever create instances of Android components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Provider`) yourself (using the `new` keyword or other means). These classes should only ever be created by the Android framework, because Android sets up the underlying `Context` for these objects and also manages the lifecycle.

In short, your architecture is flawed if you need to create an instance of an `Activity` like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Class.forName()** needs the fully qualified name - that is, the name of the package the class is contained in, plus the simple name of the class itself.

Assuming the package containing the class is called com.your.package, the code would have to be

```
    String className = "com.your.package.Tab3";  // Change here
     Object obj= null;
    try {
        obj= Class.forName(className).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can get the activity context by using below line of code

```
Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
```

Comment: My code is in a independent java class. Not in activity or service.

Comment: then you can pass the context in constructor of your java class

Comment: can I use getBaseContext() ?

Comment: No you can't use getBaseContext() from independent java class so pass context