# Shared Preferences not working

Tags: android, preferences, shared

I have a problem where my shared preferences are not working in a class file.I am confused and not able to solve it.Below is my file globalfile which saves data as follows.

```
public class globalfile extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
public static final String Pwd = "pwdKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";

private static String global_username = "null/", global_pwd = "null/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public String getusername() {

    global_username = sharedpreferences.getString(Email, "");
    return global_username;
}

public String getuserpwd() {

    global_pwd = sharedpreferences.getString(Pwd, "");
    return global_pwd;

}

public void setusername(String someVariable) {
    global_username = someVariable;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Email,global_username);
    editor.commit();

}

public void setuserpwd(String someVariable) {
    global_pwd = someVariable;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Pwd,global_pwd);
    editor.commit();

}
}
```

I first called setuserpwd() & setusername() then getuserpwd() & getusername() from another activity using object of class globalfile.But always returns null.although if I use this code without shared pref.it is working fine

Comment: where are you calling `setusername()` and `setuserpwd()`?

Comment: if `globalfile` is utility class then why extending Activity?

Answer (score 0):

[create an instance of Activity with Activity class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920907/create-an-instance-of-activity-with-activity-class-object)

Technically, you can create an instance of an Activity class. but, activity  instance would be useless because its underlying Context would not have been set up.

The rule is that you should never ever create instances of Android components (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Provider) yourself (using the new keyword or other means). These classes should only ever be created by the Android framework, because Android sets up the underlying Context for these objects and also manages the lifecycle.

I think your newly created activity object can't get actual context. so try to avoid your current flow. I suggest you to create a separate class that may use as factory class and I think your problem will solved.
 Or another solution would be like this :

```
    Context context = /*get application context*/
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
      getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    /*get value from this sharedPref*/
```

So you don't need to create activity class object and here you should avoid your previous getter method to get value.

Answer (score 0):

change you globalfile to be a utility class and not an activity so it can be used really easily by other parts of your app (that aren't an activity but have access to an android context).

```
public class Global {
    private final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String Pwd = "pwdKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";

    private static String global_username = "null/", 
        global_pwd = "null/";

    public Global(Context context) {
        this.sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public String getusername() {

        global_username = sharedpreferences.getString(Email, "null/");
        return global_username;
    }

    public String getuserpwd() {

        global_pwd = sharedpreferences.getString(Pwd, "null/");
        return global_pwd;

    }

    public void setusername(String someVariable) {
        global_username = someVariable;
        sharedpreferences.edit().putString(Email,global_username).commit();
    }

    public void setuserpwd(String someVariable) {
        global_pwd = someVariable;
        sharedpreferences.edit().putString(Pwd,global_pwd).commit();

    }
}
```

And here's how to use your new util class

```
Global global = new Global(context);
global.setusername("foo");
Log.d("TAG", "username from prefs = " + global.getusername());
global.setuserpwd("bar");
Log.d("TAG", "password from prefs = " + global.getusername());
```

Comment: Thanks, but now its working good in simple app but in my app where I am using it throwing error :java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.sony.iwashapp.globalfile; no empty constructor

Process: com.example.sony.iwashapp, PID: 18941
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.sony.iwashapp.globalfile: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.sony.iwashapp.globalfile; no empty constructor

Comment: @PrashantSinghVerma  can you accept the this answer then?

Comment: I was already using the same logic but i was wrong when i extend the class as Activity.but neverthe less I found out by reading the above comments